# AWS elastic beanstalk, serve multiple Staticfiles in Django

Tags: javascript, css, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using AWS elastic beanstalk to deploy a Django application. Here is the problem - every app in the project has a static file, but when i set option values in `myapp.config` in the `.ebextensions` file, it seems that i can only set one path for the static file. Below is the setting of static files:

```
 17  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles
 18    option_name: /static/
 19    value: polls/static/
 20 
 21  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles
 22    option_name: /static/
 23    value: control/static/
```

With the above settings in `myapp.config`, after deploying, only the `value: control/static` part works, the `value: polls/static` file seems not working. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I think I am facing the same question. Were you able to figure this out? I have an app that has its own `static` directory. Currently, it is not being served after I deploy using AWS EB.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the same namespace and option name, you override your first value `polls/static/` with the second value `control/static/`.

Maybe it should be `static/` instead, then the app will use common root and subdirectory assigned to it - `static/polls` or `static/control`?